# Unable to download the content of the folder via shared link using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the file contained in the shared folder in Onedrive using Microsoft.Graph API. My code is:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
        {
            if (graphClient == null)
            {
                // Create Microsoft Graph client.
                try
                {
                    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            }));
                    return graphClient;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
    void GetFile()
    {
    graphclient = AuthenticationHelper.GetGraphServiceClient();
    var request = graphclient.Shares[get_encoded_link()].Root.Children;
                var foundFile = await request.Request().GetAsync();

                var request1 = graphclient.Shares[get_encoded_link()].Items[foundFile[0].Id].Content;
                var content = await request1.Request().GetAsync();
    }
```

In foundfile i get the all the details of the file that are in folder. But when i request the content of the file using its id then i get this error
"Unexpected exception returned from the service"
I also try to request the content using root.itemsPath[filename]

```
var request1 = graphclient.Shares[get_encoded_link()].Root.ItemsPath[filename];
```

Shared link is created by other user with the Scope type of "anonymous" and Link type is "edit" and the user who has signed in my app is try to accessing the content of the shared folder.
But get the same error.
I can't find what i am doing wrong here!

Comment: What's the sharing link your are using? Is the link shared by the user who has signed in your app or someone else?

Comment: added the info about the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. There seems to be an issue in Microsoft Graph API when downloading content form a sharing link created by other user with the "anonymous" scope.

To see what happens here, you can take advantage of [fiddler](/questions/tagged/fiddler) and also the [source code of Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). You can download the source code form [Releases](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/releases) and add them into your project to debug.

When you call `var content = await request1.Request().GetAsync();`, it will eventually call [`SendAsync`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs#L148) method to send a request like the following:
[image]

As the [document](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm#response) said, this returns a `302 Found` response redirecting to a pre-authenticated download URL for the file. And the download URL is in the `Location` header in the response.

Graph Library [handles redirect](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs#L155-L168) with [`HandleRedirect`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs#L221) method and sends [another request with the download URL in `Location`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs#L233). However, this request returns a `403 Forbidden` response.
[image]

For `403 Forbidden` response, Graph Library [throws `UnexpectedExceptionResponse`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs#L170-L191). That's the reason why you got "Unexpected exception returned from the service." error.

**Workaround:**

We can't download the content from download URL returned by Microsoft Graph API, but we can download while using browser. So I inspected the HTTP(s) traffic while downloading with Edge and found the API endpoint used in browser is different.
[image]
As you can see it used `api.onedrive.com` as the endpoint not `graph.microsoft.com`. So we can change the `RequestUri` as a workaround.

```
var sharingLink = @"{Sharing Link}";

var foundFile = await graphClient.Shares[UrlToSharingToken(sharingLink)].Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();

var request = graphClient.Shares[UrlToSharingToken(sharingLink)].Items[foundFile[0].Id].Content.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();

request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("graph.microsoft.com", "api.onedrive.com"));

var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: Please take a look at this question  also http://stackoverflow.com/q/42774367/7695774