# Unable to send an invitation of the folder using Microsoft.Graph Api

Tags: c#, uwp, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to send an invitation for the folder but I keep getting this error:

> An invalid operation was attempted while processing this request.

My code is:

```
var graphclient = AuthenticationHelper.GetGraphServiceClient();

List<DriveRecipient> recpient = new List<DriveRecipient>() {
    new DriveRecipient {
        Email = "abcd@hotmail.com",
        Alias="abcd" } };

// var info = await graphclient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
var invite = graphclient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("trying").Invite(recpient, false, new List<string>() { "write" }, true, "inviation from xyz");
var done = await invite.Request().PostAsync();
```

Request Body is:

```
{"requireSignIn":false,
"roles":["write"],
"sendInvitation":true,
"message":"inviation from xyz",
"recipients":[{"email":"abcd@hotmail.com","alias":"abcd"}]}
```

Request Url: `https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root:/trying:/microsoft.graph.invite`

Comment: Can you show the request body that is sent with that post? Are you using OneDrive for Business or consumer?

Comment: I am using onedrive for Consumer.

Comment: I should have asked this before. Can you also share the URL that is generated as well?

Comment: please check the request url

Comment: Follow up: has anyone else encountered this issue? Was there a resolution?